# Ping particular host and move the results to file with current time stamp for every hour

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, ping

I am trying create a batch file which pings a particular host and moves the results to a file with the current time stamp for every hour. I was able to do it continuously, but the I want to know whether there is any script with which I can set the interval for which it runs the ping command.

I am successfully able to print the time stamp, ping response and the able to change the name of the file with current time stamp, but it's happening continuously. I want to do it for a time interval like say for 4hrs continuous ping then move the results to a file.

please help

Comment: @Chris - I disagree. The way I'm reading this, the question is about how to run a given command continuously for a certain length of time. The command in this case merely happens to be `ping`, and the question's title needs a complete rewrite.

Comment: And do you honestly want _four hours worth_ of ping data to be appended to a file? Assuming the ping responds at a normal rate, you're looking at almost 1 MB of data.

Comment: @SomethingDark, yes I agree, it was late last night, on my tab... I committed to flagging before realising my mistake. I couldn't remove it then, but bizarrely I can now!?. I apologise for that. :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've attempted is by **NO** means an ideal, much less precise method of doing what you desire (purely in batch), however with some tweaking and refining, or by serving as a potential route/template for similar scripts by more experienced batch scripters, I believe it may be useful:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:" %%i in ('echo %time%') do (
set /a hour=%%i+4
set /a minute=%%j
set expected=!hour!:!minute!
echo !expected!
)

for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('ping 192.168.1.1 -n 1') do (echo %%i>pinglog.txt && goto PING)

:PING
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:" %%i in ('echo %time%') do (
set current=%%i:%%j
echo !current!
)
if !current!==!expected! (
goto EOF
) else (
for /f "tokens=* skip=2" %%i in ('ping 192.168.1.1 -n 2 -w 30000') do (
echo %date% %time% %%i>>pinglog.txt && goto PING
)
)
```

Control the hour or minute interval by adding the relevant value to either, in the lines:

```
set /a hour=%%i+4 rem Here I've added 4 hours
set /a minute=%%j
```

Remove the `echo !expected!` and `echo !current!` lines if you don't wish to see the temporal progression in the cmd output, which can be minimised while the script is running.

Answer (score 1):

There is no *sane* way to do this with a command script only.

What I recommend is to write a script that performs the requested action *once*. 
Use Windows Task Scheduler to call the script every hour.